# any two open sets in the product topology contain points that differ in finitely many components

Tags: general-topology

> For non empty open sets $U$ and $V$ in the product topology $ \prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$ show that there are points $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ that only differ in finitely many coordinates.

What I have so far (not much):

> Since $U$ and $V$ are open in the product topology, both $U$ and $V$ are the union of products of open sets that differ from their corresponding topologies in only finitely many elements.

Even though the possible values that coordinates of points in $U$ can differ in only finitely many elements from possible values that coordinates of points in $V$ can take on, points in $U$ and $V$ can have infinitely many coordinates, so how would I go about finding two possibly infinitely long points that only differ in finitely many coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any open set in the product topology contains a "cylinder", that is a product of a finite number of open (proper) subsets of the $X_i$ and the remaining sets as a whole. So you just have to prove that two cylinder contain points that differ only in finitely many coordinates.

But a cylinder is defined by a finite number of open subsets in their respective topology. So let's have $C_1$ and $C_2$ open cylinder, where $C_1$ has non-surjective projection on the finite subset $I_1\subset I$. Take any point of $C_1$, and take a point of $C_2$ whose coordinates are the same outside $I_1\cup I_2$. You can find it because $C_2$ is surjective outside the coordinates in $I_2$.

With slightly more work (not much) you can reduce the coordinates where the points differ to $I_1\cap I_2$.

Fill in the formalities.

Comment: Thanks @tomasz for the spelling correction :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand; by definition, the open sets in the product topology ( for infinite index in the product ) are (EDIT unions of *) products $\Pi_{j \in J} U_j$ , where only finitely-many $U_j$, say $j=j_0,...,j_k$ are different from the whole space. Then the coordinates of any open sets can only differ in the coordinates in the $j_0,..,j_k$ spots.

EDIT: Maybe to be more specific, as Sal pointed out in his comments, a specific recipe is just taking the unions of finitely-many basic elements. Any two  open sets formed by/as the union of finitely many basic elements will differ in only finitely-many coordinates.

*Or, we could say the basic open sets are of this form.

Comment: The open sets in the product topology are **unions** of such products.

Comment: Right, so you just union two pairs of these sets, or just finitely-many of these sets. Any two choices of unions of finitely-many basic sets will differ in finitely-many coordinates. Maybe I should have written this.

Comment: @Sal: I edited to make the post more precise.

Comment: I am not sure why you still say "*by definition, the open sets in the product topology (for infinite index in the product) are products $\prod_{j\in J} U_j$*". That's incorrect; that's what I was pointing out.

Comment: O.K, you're right, let me edit. I meant to say the basic open sets are of this form. My bad.

Comment: @PassingBy thanks for your answer. I'd upvote it, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do that.